# How to get a screenshot in the windows clipboard using R?

Tags: r, clipboard, printscreen

I would like to get a screenshot in the clipboard as it could be obtained pressing the Prt Scr key on my keyboard.
I tried things like

```
cat("\U2399")
```

or using the KeyboardSimulator package

```
keybd.press('/44')
```

but it doesn't work !
Does someone have an idea ?

Comment: I'm very interested to know this too. Based on the answers to [this](https://superuser.com/q/75614/928461) question, it may not be possible without installing some other software first. I had a quick scan of the R image magick library [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/magick.pdf) but couldn't spot anything.

Comment: With image magick installed, something like this might work `system("import -window root screen.jpeg")` (it should create a file in the root directory called 'screen.jpeg') (based on [this](https://superuser.com/a/75643/928461))

Comment: In fact, I am looking for a solution that does not involve writing a file.